# Django - Postgres - 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: django, postgresql

So I get the error above when I try to use the Admin console and view one of the models in my database. The rows in my database were scraped from a website so if I'm correct, I accidentally scraped the u'\xa0' character and Django does not like this. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Now to fix it I imagine I can just run a psql query to find any u'\xa0' characters and replace them with whatever I need (empty string in this case).

I thought maybe I could use the replace function from postgres:

```
UPDATE <table> SET <field> = replace(<field>, '\xa0', '')
```

but it doesn't appear to be working.

Any tips?

Error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Python string has changed greatly from 2.8 to 3.x

Comment: @yehe 2.7.11+ in my virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into a similar problem, this is what I did. I pulled my database into a csv file so I could easily search through it with ctrl+f. I then figured out the ascii characters my database couldn't understand and I adjusted them to suit my needs. I overwrote my database with the adjusted csv.

My database information was scraped from the web so in the future I will make sure my database accepts the information that I scrape.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've implemented `__unicode__()` method and instead of unicode you're returning a string.

So you're doing this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % self.something
```

Instead of:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s" % self.something
```

Comment: I haven't implemented unicode. I think my possible solutions are pray that I can upgrade python and all my packages still work or fix my database information.